# SQL : Finding duplicates and flag in separate column with Case

Tags: sql, duplicates, impala, hue

I am trying to find duplicates in the table and wanted to add a new flag column.
Sample data below :

```
Column A        Column B
1                888
1                999
1                777
2                444
2                444
3                555
4                222
```

Desired output :

```
Column A        Column B         Flag_output
1                888              DUPLICATE
1                999              DUPLICATE
1                777              DUPLICATE
2                444              NULL
2                444              NULL
3                555              NULL
4                222              NULL
```

**case 1**: When Column A has the same values with different values in Column B (e.g. value *1* in Column A) - should be marked as DUPLICATE

**case 2**: When Column A has the same values with the same values in Column B in multiple rows(e.g. value *2* in column A) - should be marked as NULL

**case 3**: When Column A and Column B has unique values (e.g. value *3* and *4* in Column A) - Also should be marked as NULL

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(b) over (partition by a) <> max(b) over (partition by a)
             then 'DUPLICATE'
        end) as flag_output
from t;
```

Comment: Really Appreciated. It almost worked however I would like to ask if continuing the same, could it be possible to add the case where if Column_A and Column_B has one more record with values 1 and 777 respectively and in desired output, we want that two rows of 1 and 777 marked as NULL? and First two rows with values 1  888 and 1 999 would be as DUPLICATE
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @FarhanPanja . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  Your comment sounds like a different question, which should be asked as a *new* question.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff Thank you for the suggestions.
I have posted a new question. Could it be possible for you to have a look and help out there? Link below :
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66392429/sql-is-there-any-way-to-find-duplicates-and-flag-them-as-new-column-with-case)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```js
UPDATE MISC.YOUR_TABLE SET FLAG_OUTPUT='DUPLICATE' WHERE COLUMN_A=
(SELECT COLUMN_A FROM (SELECT COLUMN_A, COUNT(*) A_COUNT FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B FROM MISC.YOUR_TABLE) Q GROUP BY COLUMN_A) R WHERE A_COUNT>1)
```

[image]

or if you're not updating an actual column, you could do this:

```html
SELECT  YT.COLUMN_A, YT.COLUMN_B, DUPQ.FLAG_OUTPUT
FROM    MISC.YOUR_TABLE YT
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT COLUMN_A, 'DUPLICATE' FLAG_OUTPUT FROM (SELECT COLUMN_A, COUNT(*) A_COUNT FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B FROM MISC.YOUR_TABLE) Q GROUP BY COLUMN_A) R WHERE A_COUNT>1) DUPQ
        ON YT.COLUMN_A=DUPQ.COLUMN_A
```