# SQL : Is there any way to find Duplicates and flag them as new column with case

Tags: sql, duplicates, case, impala, hue

I am trying to find duplicates in the table and wanted to add a new flag column.
Sample data below :

```
Column A        Column B
1                888
1                999
1                777
1                777
2                444
2                444
3                555
4                222
-5               333
-5               672
-5               045
```

Desired output :

```
Column A        Column B         Flag_output
1                888              DUPLICATE
1                999              DUPLICATE
1                777              NULL
1                777              NULL
2                444              NULL
2                444              NULL
3                555              NULL
4                222              NULL
-5               333              DUPLICATE
-5               672              DUPLICATE
-5               045              DUPLICATE
```

**case 1**: When Column A has the same values with different values in Column B (e.g. value *1* in Column A) - should be marked as DUPLICATE

**case 2**: When Column A has the same values with the same values in Column B in multiple rows(e.g. value *2* in column A) - should be marked as NULL

**case 3**: When Column A and Column B has unique values (e.g. value *3* and *4* in Column A) - Also should be marked as NULL

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand how the rows for "1" have different values for the flag, based on your conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I can phrase your conditions as when the minimum and maximum values of `b` are different for `a`, then label as `'duplicate'`.

For this, use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(b) over (partition by a) <> max(b) over (partition by a)
             then 'duplicate'
        end) as flag_output
from t;
```

Based on the data, you seem to want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by a, b) = 1 and
                  count(*) over (partition by a) > 1
             then 'duplicate'
        end) as flag_output
from t;
```

That is, to flag singleton values only when there is more than one value for `a`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** @Gordon Linoff [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66392451/14956277) while I was typing. Definitely try his solution first as it's likely to be more performant than this.

---

Given the following:

```
A   | B
--- | ---
1   | 888   
1   | 999
1   | 777
1   | 777
```

You'd encounter `A=1` for the first time, so it can't be a `DUPLICATE` and must be `NULL`.

```
A   | B   | Result
--- | --- | ---
1   | 888 | NULL     
1   | 999 |
1   | 777 | 
1   | 777 |
```

Then you'd encounter `A=1` for a second time with a different value  of `B`. This marks both rows as `DUPLICATE`.

```
A   | B   | Result
--- | --- | ---
1   | 888 | DUPLICATE   
1   | 999 | DUPLICATE
1   | 777 | 
1   | 777 |
```

There's a third instance of `A=1` and it also has a different value of `B`. All three are `DUPLICATE`s.

```
A   | B   | Result
--- | --- | ---
1   | 888 | DUPLICATE   
1   | 999 | DUPLICATE
1   | 777 | DUPLICATE
1   | 777 |
```

The fourth time you see `A=1` it has a value for `B` that you've seen before (`B=777`) which marks both rows as `NULL`.

```
A   | B   | Result
--- | --- | ---
1   | 888 | DUPLICATE   
1   | 999 | DUPLICATE
1   | 777 | NULL
1   | 777 | NULL
```

---

My solution counts the instances of each value of `A` in the table and the number of matches for each `A, B` pair. These sub-results are joined to the main table to get your results. [Try it out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/744b5/2/0).

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE Sample (A int, B int)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT s.A, s.B,
  CASE 
    WHEN m.Matches > 1 THEN NULL
    WHEN i.Instances = 1 THEN NULL
    ELSE 'DUPLICATE'    
  END AS Result
FROM Sample s 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT A, COUNT(*) AS Instances FROM Sample GROUP BY A) i
    ON s.A = i.A
  INNER JOIN (SELECT A, B, COUNT(*) AS Matches FROM Sample GROUP BY A, B) m
    ON s.A = m.A AND s.B = m.B
ORDER BY A, B
```